# HTML Input Array: How to get html input array values with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input

I have this code which works fine!:

```html
<script>
function get(userfirstname, userlastname){
 alert(userfirstname);

 return false;
}
</script>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="userfirstname">
    <input type="text" name="userlastname">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return get(userfirstname.value, userlastname.value);">
</form>
```

i am trying to catch the input values with an array like this:

```html
<script>
function get(user){
 alert(user["firstname"].value);

 return false;
}
</script>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user[firstname]">
    <input type="text" name="user[lastname]">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return get(user);">
</form>
```

i tried so many different scenarios, no point :(

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: you can't.. in js you have to get them in objects to do this

Comment: hello!, thank you for your comment, how can i get them in object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply target the `form` element inside your `onclick` handler, query all `input` elements to iterate over them and build the `array` you are looking for.

Here is an example of what you could do to build an array of objects holding each input elements name and value, excluding disabled once and the submit element.

```js
function get(evt){
  var fields = [];
  event.target.parentElement
  .querySelectorAll('input:not([disabled]):not([type="submit"])').forEach(function(e) {
    fields.push({name: e.name, value: e.value}); 
  })
  console.log(fields);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Name"><br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Surename"><br>
  <input type="text" name="foo" value="foo will be excluded" disabled><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="return get();">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this work as HTML Array Input ?, Like user[firstname] and user[lastname] ??

Comment: Not sure if there is anything like *HTML Array Input*. There might be server side languages that now how to deal with these type of input field naming styles,  to convert them to an `array`, just like PHP does, i think. But may i ask why this is so important to you ? From the example i gave you, you can build an array or object, with what ever structure you like. You do not need the array syntax inside the name attribute.

Comment: I tried your code! it worked for me, Thank you, what i mean HTML Array Input, is this:
    <input type="text" name="user[firstname]">
    <input type="text" name="user[lastname]">

Comment: i want the client side to handle it, because i want to use it as Ajax to login with it, but the Framework i am working on, works only with html input arrays.. it is a little bit complicated, the PHP framework i am using is Yii2,
this is the first time i get stuck with such a stupid question like this, but no body thought about it that's the problem :), Thank you for caring ;)

ofcourse i am not gone use firstname or lastname to login with it though :D

Answer (score 1):

**A jQuery Approach to get this**

```
function get(){
    var fields = [];
    var arr = $('form').not('input[type="submit"]').find('input[type="text"]')
    $(arr).each(function(i,val){
        fields.push({name:$(val).attr('name'),value:$(val).val()})
    })
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bit over complicated. With jQuery you could simply use [.serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), which does exactly that, and a bit more. ;)

Comment: Your code worked! Thank you :), how ever, i want to use javascript code, so mr @DavidDomain , fixed the issue :)